# How to set an event for all cells in WPF Datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I need `OnDragEnter` event for every cell on my WPF Datagrid.
I tried this :

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type my:DataGridCell}" x:Key="RowTemplate">
    <ContentPresenter DragEnter="ContentPresenter_DragEnter" >
    </ContentPresenter>
</ControlTemplate>
```

But doesn't seem to work. Any ideas people?

---

**Edit:** Thanks for the responses, i realized that i was facing another problem though :
My real problem was that the `TextBox` control **always marks drag and drop events as handled** so even if you set `AllowDrop="True"` it will look like AllowDrop is not working. It is not a bug, this behavior is actually by design.

I used the Preview Events to anticipate to this, and be able to handle D'n'D events.

```
<TextBox
    AllowDrop="True"
    PreviewDragEnter="TextBox_PreviewDragOver" 
    PreviewDragOver="TextBox_PreviewDragOver"  
    PreviewDrop="TextBox_PreviewDrop">
<TextBox/>
```

Hope this helps.
I am marking your responses as answers as they were accurate regarding the initial question.

Comment: I haven't tried this so I won't post it as an answer, but according to the docs, the DragEnter event is a bubbling routed event, so you should be able to handle it at the DataGrid level, and DragEnter events on cells will "bubble up".  The downside is this won't work if a lower-level element such as a cell marks the event as handled, though you can get around this by calling `AddHandler` in code with `handledEventsToo` set to true i.e. `AddHandler(DragDrop.DragEnterEvent, myDragHandler, true)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close.

You need to set `AllowDrop`, and you need to set it **at or below** the level you set the event handler.  For example:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type my:DataGridCell}" x:Key="RowTemplate"> 
  <ContentPresenter DragEnter="ContentPresenter_DragEnter" AllowDrop="true"> 
  </ContentPresenter> 
</ControlTemplate>
```

Drag/drop events are only sent to `UIElements` that have `AllowDrop="true"`.  From there they bubble up the tree until they are handled.

Note that you can add the `DragEnter` handler on the `DataGrid` itself instead of on each cell, but if you want information on which cell is the drop target you should still set `AllowDrop="true"` at the cell level.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need to set the AllowDrop property to true on the cell.  Without this set to true, the element won't participate in the drag/drop events.